# Styling/customizing a twitter widget?

Tags: css, twitter, widget

Twitter seems to have removed most of the ability to styling the widgets. But thing is I keep seeing websites with custom widgets. Is there any way to still do it? I saw a tutorial on taking the JS and the CSS and placing it on your own server. It doesn't seem to work that way anymore, though. Does anyone have a clue on how to do this? I need my widget to fit the theme of my website perfectly.

I'm talking about like removing the widget header, hide pictures from the feed, etc.

Comment: Solved this issue by using a custom script from TweetGrid.

Answer (score 1):

This JS snippet will let you add custom CSS styles to the Twitter embed widget: https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1